# Jquery tools validator - change where messages are displayed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have widget that hides field, (which I must validate), and creates another field. Validation message now is displayed at the top of the **window** and it should be next to created field. Any ideas?

```
$('#hiddenField').validator({ messageClass: "invalid_tooltip", lang: 'en', position: "center right", offset: [0, 6] });

<select id="hiddenField" style="display:none">
    some values
</select>

<span>
    <input ...>
</span>
```

Comment: Remove the position property and try again.  Post a jsfiddle.net if possible

Comment: Removing the position had no effect

Comment: How about posting a jsfiddle of your problem or an send me a link where I can see it online?  It's hard to guess what the problem might be.

Comment: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ranentil/MCt83/11/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your inline code here:

```
visibility: visible; position: absolute; top: -1.5px; left: 75px;
```

Since it appears this code is being generated by your external resource, and that external resource is minified; I recommend just trying to use a different library.  The latest version of jQuery UI has tooltips, plus there are tons of other tooltip libraries for jQuery that are available - the one you're using apparently isn't very good...

Ref.  http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Ref.  http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/